# Duplication on Sql table

Tags: sql

I am having huge issue on this duplicate error. There are two different barcodes I need to scan. Procedures are basically as; first you scan to orange barcode and secondly yellow barcodes every time to complete procedure and if operator mistakenly scan one particular barcode (orange or yellow) more than one times on a row (continuously), system should ignore duplicated entry.
 Table_1 is representing yellow barcodes and Table_2 is representing orange barcodes.

I have program indicated below does not prevent operator to scan one particular (yellow or orange) multiple times.

Table_1 contain two columns (Serial and ID) Table_2 contain one column (program)

```
SELECT MAX(Serial) as Serial_, ID, COUNT(*) as total
FROM
     (SELECT SERIAL, ID, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_Time) AS NUM1 FROM TABLE_1) 
   AS X
   FULL OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT PROGRAM, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_Time) AS NUM2 FROM TABLE_2) 
   AS Y
ON X.NUM1 = Y.NUM2
GROUP BY Serial,ID, Program
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the problem exactly? Not only is the guess-work a bit difficult here, but it could also be largely erroneous without proper information. `System should ignore duplicate entry` - does it mean that the record shouldn't be inserted in the table in the first place? Which field is the barcode stored in? What are `Serial`, `ID` and `Program` respectively? Could you share some data to give a better idea on what's the output produced and why it is problematic, thereby describing what you expect it to look like? Thanks....

Comment: So this is your query to find the duplication errors? May I ask how do you know that row_number =1 in both tables is referring to the same operational scan of two barcodes at approximately the same time? I see you have a windowing group with the order by date_time but that doesn't guarantee they belong together.

Comment: System should not insert duplicated entry into table